# Computing KL divergence for many distributions

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a matrix of test probability distributions:

```
qs = np.array([[0.1, 0.6], 
               [0.9, 0.4] ])
```

(sums up to 1 in each column) and "true" distribution:

```
p = np.array([0.5, 0.5])
```

I would like to calculate the KL divergence from `p` to every column of `qs` *in TensorFlow*. I know that there is a function `tf.distributions.kl_divergence`, but it takes just two distributions...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution works for arbitrarily many columns and uses TensorFlow only:

```
qs = np.array([[0.9, 0.6, 0.4, 0.5],
               [0.1, 0.4, 0.6, 0.5]])
p = np.array([0.5, 0.5])
# Format `p` to a column vector, for constistency reason
p_t = p.reshape([-1, 1])

# Convert to categorical distributions. Transpose part is important
dist_qs = tf.distributions.Categorical(probs=tf.transpose(qs))
dist_p = tf.distributions.Categorical(probs=tf.transpose(p))

# Calculate KL divergences for qs and broadcasted p 
tf.distributions.kl_divergence(dist_p, dist_qs).eval()
```

This gives:

```
array([0.51082562, 0.020411  , 0.020411  , 0.])
```

what looks as a promising result.

Answer (score 1):

You could loop through the columns:

```
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
A = tf.distributions.Categorical(probs=[0.5, 0.5])

for i in range(2):
    B = tf.distributions.Categorical(probs=list(qs[:,i]))
    print(tf.distributions.kl_divergence(A, B).eval())
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's how to do it:

```
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
A = tf.distributions.Categorical(probs=[0.1, 0.6])
B = tf.distributions.Categorical(probs=[0.9, 0.4])
print(tf.distributions.kl_divergence(A, B).eval())
```

Output: `0.7773577`

Comment: Not sure this is what OP asks: first, OP's distros are actually `[0.1, 0.9]` & `[0.6, 0.4]` (each one summing up to 1); second, OP asks for the KL of *both* these distros from `[0.5, 0.5]`