# Compute KL divergence between rows of a matrix and a vector

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have a matrix (numpy 2d array) in which each row is a valid probability distribution. I have another vector (numpy 1d array), again a prob dist. I need to compute KL divergence between each row of the matrix and the vector. Is it possible to do this without using for loops?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51770349/3337089) asks the same thing, but none of the answers solve my problem. One of them suggests to use for loop which I want to avoid since I have large data. Another answer provides a solution in tensorflow, but I want for numpy arrays.

[scipy.stats.entropy](http://scipy.github.io/devdocs/generated/scipy.stats.entropy.html) computes KL divergence between 2 vectors, but I couldn't get how to use it when one of them is a matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function [`scipy.stats.entropy`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.entropy.html) can, in fact, do the vectorized calculation, but you have to reshape the arguments appropriately for it to work.  When the inputs are two-dimensional arrays, `entropy` expects the *columns* to hold the probability vectors.  In the case where `p` is two-dimensional and `q` is one-dimensional, a trivial dimension must be added to `q` to make the arguments compatible for broadcasting.

Here's an example.  First, the imports:

```
In [10]: import numpy as np                                                     

In [11]: from scipy.stats import entropy
```

Create a two-dimensional `p` whose rows are the probability vectors, and a one-dimensional probability vector `q`:

```
In [12]: np.random.seed(8675309)                                                

In [13]: p = np.random.rand(3, 5)                                               

In [14]: p /= p.sum(axis=1, keepdims=True)                                      

In [15]: q = np.random.rand(5)                                                  

In [16]: q /= q.sum()                                                           

In [17]: p                                                                      
Out[17]: 
array([[0.32085531, 0.29660176, 0.14113073, 0.07988999, 0.1615222 ],
       [0.05870513, 0.15367858, 0.29585406, 0.01298657, 0.47877566],
       [0.1914319 , 0.29324935, 0.1093297 , 0.17710131, 0.22888774]])

In [18]: q                                                                      
Out[18]: array([0.06804561, 0.35392387, 0.29008139, 0.04580467, 0.24214446])
```

For comparison with the vectorized result, here's the result computed using a Python loop.

```
In [19]: [entropy(t, q) for t in p]                                             
Out[19]: [0.32253909299531597, 0.17897138916539493, 0.2627905326857023]
```

To make `entropy` do the vectorized calculation, the *columns* of the first argument must be the probability vectors, so we'll transpose `p`.  Then, to make `q` compatible with `p.T`, we'll reshape it into a two-dimensional array with shape (5, 1) (i.e. it contains a single column):

```
In [20]: entropy(p.T, q.reshape(-1, 1))                                         
Out[20]: array([0.32253909, 0.17897139, 0.26279053])
```

*Note*: It is tempting to use `q.T` as the second argument, but that won't work.  In NumPy, the transpose operation only swaps the lengths of existing dimensions--it never creates new dimensions.  So the transpose of a one-dimensional array is itself.  That is, `q.T` is the same shape as `q`.

---

*Older version of this answer follows...*

You can use [`scipy.special.kl_div`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.kl_div.html) or [`scipy.special.rel_entr`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.rel_entr.html) to do this.  Here's an example.

```
In [17]: import numpy as np 
    ...: from scipy.stats import entropy 
    ...: from scipy.special import kl_div, rel_entr
```

Make `p` and `q` for the example.
`p` has shape (3, 5); the rows are the probability distributions. `q` is a 1-d array with length 5.

```
In [18]: np.random.seed(8675309) 
    ...: p = np.random.rand(3, 5) 
    ...: p /= p.sum(axis=1, keepdims=True) 
    ...: q = np.random.rand(5) 
    ...: q /= q.sum()
```

This is the calculation that you want, using a Python loop and `scipy.stats.entropy`.  I include this here so the result can be compared to the vectorized calculation below.

```
In [19]: [entropy(t, q) for t in p]                                                                                                          
Out[19]: [0.32253909299531597, 0.17897138916539493, 0.2627905326857023]
```

We have constructed `p` and `q` so that the probability vectors
each sum to 1.  In this case, the above result can also be
computed in a vectorized calculation with `scipy.special.rel_entr` or `scipy.special.kl_div`. (I recommend `rel_entr`.  `kl_div` adds and subtracts additional terms that will ultimately cancel out in the sum, so it does a bit more work than necessary.)
These functions compute only the point-wise part of the calculations;
you have to sum the result to get the actual entropy or divergence.

```
In [20]: rel_entr(p, q).sum(axis=1)                                                                              
Out[20]: array([0.32253909, 0.17897139, 0.26279053])

In [21]: kl_div(p, q).sum(axis=1)                                                                                
Out[21]: array([0.32253909, 0.17897139, 0.26279053])
```

Comment: `[entropy(t, q) for t in p]`. This is exactly I want to avoid. I need this to compute Inception score. Typically I'll have rows in the order of 50K. So, I want to know if there is any vectorized way.

Comment: Read the rest of the answer. :)  I included that so you could compare the results.